# i need copy command support

Tags: windows, cmd

Currently I have a directory tree system like the image:

[image]

I would like someone to help me create a small piece of code. I want to search all directories, I will see a folder named "C" as above, copy all the data and rename it to a higher level folder, will copy to another folder with the name E . You can only copy the A1 folder and contain the C folder inside. I'm using windows 10. Thank you very much.

Comment: "...copy all the data and rename it to a higher level folder, will copy to another folder with the name E ..." is not clear. Please clarify your question with sample paths. Do you want to copy individual files or the folder & its contents?

Comment: I want to copy all the data of folder C to another folder and rename the folder to A1 if that folder C is in folder A1, folder C to A2 if that folder is in A2, nothing but copy item C.

Answer (score 0):

In **PowerShell**, the [`Copy-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/copy-item?view=powershell-7.2) cmdlet can rename an item while copying. So you want to:

1. Use `Get-ChildItem` to find all subfolders of the source named "C".
2. Pipe these to `Copy-Item`
3. Construct the destination path and name using [`Join-Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/join-path?view=powershell-7.2).

```
$Source = 'C:\Source' ### Parent folder of folders "A", "B", etc.
$Dest   = 'D:\Dest' ### Destination path for copied folders

#    Destination root must exist:
If (!(Test-Path $Dest)) {mkdir $Dest | out-null}

Get-ChildItem -Path $Source -Filter 'C' -Directory -Recurse |
    Copy-Item -Destination {Join-Path $Dest $_.Parent.Name} -Recurse
```

Which can be shortened using positional parameters and aliases to:

```
gci $Source 'C' -ad -s |
    copy -Dest {Join-Path $Dest $_.Parent.Name} -Recurse
```

Comment: can you help me with another command .
For example: I want to find folder "C" if there is folder "C", then copy folder "B2" containing only that letter "C" and other similar folders. Thanks for bothering everyone